# Parse JSON to store in ruby on rails database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

The string is of the form

```
{"session":"a24186c2-5536-1734-42cc-3eb50e625964","time":1392862093110,"prettyTime":"Wed Feb 19 2014 21:08:13 GMT-0500 (EST)","timeDrift":0,"event":"Started session"},{"session":"a24186c2-5536-1734-42cc-3eb50e625964","time":1392844105595,"prettyTime":"Wed Feb 19 2014 16:08:25 GMT-0500 (EST)","timeDrift":-18000293.5,"event":"User logged in","parameters":{"username":"s1group1","firstName":"student","lastName":"1group1","className":"dragon"}},{"session":"71ffa2dc-ffec-9276-063f-82cd4bd43c70","time":1392844138219,"prettyTime":"Wed Feb 19 2014 16:08:58 GMT-0500 (EST)","timeDrift":-18000402.5,"event":"User logged in","parameters":{"username":"s1group1","firstName":"student","lastName":"1group1","className":"dragon"}},{"session":"71ffa2dc-ffec-9276-063f-82cd4bd43c70","time":1392862136734,"prettyTime":"Wed Feb 19 2014 21:08:56 GMT-0500 (EST)","timeDrift":0,"event":"Started session"},{"session":"6f3fe618-b934-a66a-aae4-5193d9106535","time":1392862145281,"prettyTime":"Wed Feb 19 2014 21:09:05 GMT-0500 (EST)","timeDrift":0,"event":"Started session"},{"session":"6f3fe618-b934-a66a-aae4-5193d9106535","time":1392844147075,"prettyTime":"Wed Feb 19 2014 16:09:07 GMT-0500 (EST)","timeDrift":-18000245,"event":"Moved to","parameters":{"title":"Office"}},{"session":"6f3fe618-b934-a66a-aae4-5193d9106535","time":1392844147067,"prettyTime":"Wed Feb 19 2014 16:09:07 GMT-0500 (EST)","timeDrift":-18000245,"event":"User logged in","parameters":{"username":"s1group1","firstName":"student","lastName":"1group1","className":"dragon"}},{"session":"6f3fe618-b934-a66a-aae4-5193d9106535","time":1392844150345,"prettyTime":"Wed Feb 19 2014 16:09:10 GMT-0500 (EST)","timeDrift":-18000245,"event":"User logged out"},{"session":"6f3fe618-b934-a66a-aae4-5193d9106535","time":1392844150346,"prettyTime":"Wed Feb 19 2014 16:09:10 GMT-0500 (EST)","timeDrift":-18000245,"event":"Ended session"},{"session":"277515ea-7433-e097-48c5-ece5f9753303","time":1392908888831,"prettyTime":"Thu Feb 20 2014 10:08:08 GMT-0500 (EST)","timeDrift":-18005801.5,"event":"Started session"},{"session":"277515ea-7433-e097-48c5-ece5f9753303","time":1392908888831,"prettyTime":"Thu Feb 20 2014 10:08:08 GMT-0500 (EST)","timeDrift":-18005801.5,"event":"User logged in","parameters":{"username":"s1group1","firstName":"student","lastName":"1group1","className":"dragon"}},{"session":"277515ea-7433-e097-48c5-ece5f9753303","time":1392908892346,"prettyTime":"Thu Feb 20 2014 10:08:12 GMT-0500 (EST)","timeDrift":-18005801.5,"event":"Moved to","parameters":{"title":"Case Log"}},{"session":"277515ea-7433-e097-48c5-ece5f9753303","time":1392908896382,"prettyTime":"Thu Feb 20 2014 10:08:16 GMT-0500 (EST)","timeDrift":-18005801.5,"event":"Moved to","parameters":{"title":"Case 2: Challenge 1"}},{"session":"277515ea-7433-e097-48c5-ece5f9753303","time":1392908896382,"prettyTime":"Thu Feb 20 2014 10:08:16 GMT-0500 (EST)","timeDrift":-18005801.5,"event":"Started challenge","parameters":{"title":"Case 2: Challenge 1","route":"case2/challenge1","case":1,"challenge":2}},{"session":"277515ea-7433-e097-48c5-ece5f9753303","time":1392908896601,"prettyTime":"Thu Feb 20 2014 10:08:16 GMT-0500 (EST)","timeDrift":-18005801.5,"event":"Opened info"},{"session":"277515ea-7433-e097-48c5-ece5f9753303","time":1392908898233,"prettyTime":"Thu Feb 20 2014 10:08:18 GMT-0500 (EST)","timeDrift":-18005801.5,"event":"Closed info"},{"session":"277515ea-7433-e097-48c5-ece5f9753303","time":1392908899921,"prettyTime":"Thu Feb 20 2014 10:08:19 GMT-0500 (EST)","timeDrift":-18005801.5,"event":"Selected parent","parameters":{"alleles":"a:T,b:T,a:m,b:m,a:w,b:w,a:h,b:h,a:C,b:C,a:B,b:B,a:Fl,b:Fl,a:Hl,b:hl,a:A1,b:A1,a:D,b:D,a:Bog,b:Bog,a:rh,b:rh","sex":1}},{"session":"277515ea-7433-e097-48c5-ece5f9753303","time":1392908901545,"prettyTime":"Thu Feb 20 2014 10:08:21 GMT-0500 (EST)","timeDrift":-18005801.5,"event":"Completed meiosis","parameters":{"sex":1}},{"session":"277515ea-7433-e097-48c5-ece5f9753303","time":1392908902959,"prettyTime":"Thu Feb 20 2014 10:08:22 GMT-0500 (EST)","timeDrift":-18005801.5,"event":"Selected gamete","parameters":{"alleles":"T,m,w,h,C,B,Fl,Hl,A1,D,Bog,rh","sex":1}},{"session":"277515ea-7433-e097-48c5-ece5f9753303","time":1392909523246,"prettyTime":"Thu Feb 20 2014 10:18:43 GMT-0500 (EST)","timeDrift":-18005801.5,"event":"Moved to","parameters":{"title":"Case Log"}},{"session":"277515ea-7433-e097-48c5-ece5f9753303","time":1392909523265,"prettyTime":"Thu Feb 20 2014 10:18:43 GMT-0500 (EST)","timeDrift":-18005801.5,"event":"Closed info"},{"session":"277515ea-7433-e097-48c5-ece5f9753303","time":1392909525004,"prettyTime":"Thu Feb 20 2014 10:18:45 GMT-0500 (EST)","timeDrift":-18005801.5,"event":"Closed info"},{"session":"277515ea-7433-e097-48c5-ece5f9753303","time":1392909526551,"prettyTime":"Thu Feb 20 2014 10:18:46 GMT-0500 (EST)","timeDrift":-18005801.5,"event":"Moved to","parameters":{"title":"Case 13: Challenge 1"}},{"session":"277515ea-7433-e097-48c5-ece5f9753303","time":1392909526552,"prettyTime":"Thu Feb 20 2014 10:18:46 GMT-0500 (EST)","timeDrift":-18005801.5,"event":"Started challenge","parameters":{"title":"Case 13: Challenge 1","route":"case13/challenge1","case":1,"challenge":1}},{"session":"277515ea-7433-e097-48c5-ece5f9753303","time":1392909526557,"prettyTime":"Thu Feb 20 2014 10:18:46 GMT-0500 (EST)","timeDrift":-18005801.5,"event":"Closed info"},{"session":"277515ea-7433-e097-48c5-ece5f9753303","time":1392909526825,"prettyTime":"Thu Feb 20 2014 10:18:46 GMT-0500 (EST)","timeDrift":-18005801.5,"event":"Closed info"},{"session":"277515ea-7433-e097-48c5-ece5f9753303","time":1392909526892,"prettyTime":"Thu Feb 20 2014 10:18:46 GMT-0500 (EST)","timeDrift":-18005801.5,"event":"Opened info"},{"session":"277515ea-7433-e097-48c5-ece5f9753303","time":1392909529014,"prettyTime":"Thu Feb 20 2014 10:18:49 GMT-0500 (EST)","timeDrift":-18005801.5,"event":"Closed info"},{"session":"277515ea-7433-e097-48c5-ece5f9753303","time":1392909530316,"prettyTime":"Thu Feb 20 2014 10:18:50 GMT-0500 (EST)","timeDrift":-18005801.5,"event":"Selected parent","parameters":{"alleles":"a:T,b:T,a:m,b:m,a:W,b:W,a:h,b:h,a:C,b:C,a:B,b:B,a:fl,b:fl,a:Hl,b:hl,a:A1,b:A1,a:D,b:D,a:Bog,b:Bog,a:Rh,b:Rh","sex":1}},{"session":"277515ea-7433-e097-48c5-ece5f9753303","time":1392909532339,"prettyTime":"Thu Feb 20 2014 10:18:52 GMT-0500 (EST)","timeDrift":-18005801.5,"event":"Selected parent","parameters":{"alleles":"a:T,b:T,a:m,b:m,a:w,b:w,a:H,b:H,a:C,b:C,a:B,b:B,a:Fl,b:Fl,a:Hl,b:Hl,a:A1,b:A1,a:D,a:Bog,a:Rh","sex":0}},{"session":"277515ea-7433-e097-48c5-ece5f9753303","time":1392909533840,"prettyTime":"Thu Feb 20 2014 10:18:53 GMT-0500 (EST)","timeDrift":-18005801.5,"event":"Bred dragons","parameters":{"mother":"a:T,b:T,a:m,b:m,a:W,b:W,a:h,b:h,a:C,b:C,a:B,b:B,a:fl,b:fl,a:Hl,b:hl,a:A1,b:A1,a:D,b:D,a:Bog,b:Bog,a:Rh,b:Rh","father":"a:T,b:T,a:m,b:m,a:w,b:w,a:H,b:H,a:C,b:C,a:B,b:B,a:Fl,b:Fl,a:Hl,b:Hl,a:A1,b:A1,a:D,a:Bog,a:Rh"}},{"session":"ccdf88d4-9928-c651-0c92-313e3d674227","time":1392909555848,"prettyTime":"Thu Feb 20 2014 10:19:15 GMT-0500 (EST)","timeDrift":-18005801,"event":"User logged in","parameters":{"username":"s1group1","firstName":"student","lastName":"1group1","className":"dragon"}},{"session":"ccdf88d4-9928-c651-0c92-313e3d674227","time":1392909554985,"prettyTime":"Thu Feb 20 2014 10:19:14 GMT-0500 (EST)","timeDrift":-18005801,"event":"Started session"},{"session":"ccdf88d4-9928-c651-0c92-313e3d674227","time":1392909555918,"prettyTime":"Thu Feb 20 2014 10:19:15 GMT-0500 (EST)","timeDrift":-18005801,"event":"Started challenge","parameters":{"title":"Case 13: Challenge 1","route":"case13/challenge1","case":1,"challenge":1}},{"session":"ccdf88d4-9928-c651-0c92-313e3d674227","time":1392909555917,"prettyTime":"Thu Feb 20 2014 10:19:15 GMT-0500 (EST)","timeDrift":-18005801,"event":"Moved to","parameters":{"title":"Case 13: Challenge 1"}},{"session":"ccdf88d4-9928-c651-0c92-313e3d674227","time":1392909556220,"prettyTime":"Thu Feb 20 2014 10:19:16 GMT-0500 (EST)","timeDrift":-18005801,"event":"Opened info"},{"session":"ccdf88d4-9928-c651-0c92-313e3d674227","time":1392909559565,"prettyTime":"Thu Feb 20 2014 10:19:19 GMT-0500 (EST)","timeDrift":-18005801,"event":"Closed info"},{"session":"47997fdf-02f2-e26f-b233-6fa5f6896ed3","time":1392927580329,"prettyTime":"Thu Feb 20 2014 15:19:40 GMT-0500 (EST)","timeDrift":0,"event":"Started session"},{"session":"47997fdf-02f2-e26f-b233-6fa5f6896ed3","time":1392909574938,"prettyTime":"Thu Feb 20 2014 10:19:34 GMT-0500 (EST)","timeDrift":-18005901.5,"event":"User logged in","parameters":{"username":"s1group1","firstName":"student","lastName":"1group1","className":"dragon"}},{"session":"47997fdf-02f2-e26f-b233-6fa5f6896ed3","time":1392909575005,"prettyTime":"Thu Feb 20 2014 10:19:35 GMT-0500 (EST)","timeDrift":-18005901.5,"event":"Started challenge","parameters":{"title":"Case 13: Challenge 1","route":"case13/challenge1","case":1,"challenge":1}},{"session":"47997fdf-02f2-e26f-b233-6fa5f6896ed3","time":1392909575004,"prettyTime":"Thu Feb 20 2014 10:19:35 GMT-0500 (EST)","timeDrift":-18005901.5,"event":"Moved to","parameters":{"title":"Case 13: Challenge 1"}},{"session":"47997fdf-02f2-e26f-b233-6fa5f6896ed3","time":1392909575283,"prettyTime":"Thu Feb 20 2014 10:19:35 GMT-0500 (EST)","timeDrift":-18005901.5,"event":"Opened info"},{"session":"47997fdf-02f2-e26f-b233-6fa5f6896ed3","time":1392909577439,"prettyTime":"Thu Feb 20 2014 10:19:37 GMT-0500 (EST)","timeDrift":-18005901.5,"event":"Closed info"},{"session":"e8a14c99-b18a-20a5-1d7e-cea199a1f605","time":1393264714143,"prettyTime":"Mon Feb 24 2014 12:58:34 GMT-0500 (EST)","timeDrift":0,"event":"Started session"},{"session":"e8a14c99-b18a-20a5-1d7e-cea199a1f605","time":1393246740044,"prettyTime":"Mon Feb 24 2014 07:59:00 GMT-0500 (EST)","timeDrift":-18000716,"event":"User logged in","parameters":{"username":"s1group1","firstName":"student","lastName":"1group1","className":"dragon"}},{"session":"e8a14c99-b18a-20a5-1d7e-cea199a1f605","time":1393246740057,"prettyTime":"Mon Feb 24 2014 07:59:00 GMT-0500 (EST)","timeDrift":-18000716,"event":"Moved to","parameters":{"title":"Office"}},{"session":"e8a14c99-b18a-20a5-1d7e-cea199a1f605","time":1393246757111,"prettyTime":"Mon Feb 24 2014 07:59:17 GMT-0500 (EST)","timeDrift":-18000716,"event":"Moved to","parameters":{"title":"Case Log"}},{"session":"e8a14c99-b18a-20a5-1d7e-cea199a1f605","time":1393246826601,"prettyTime":"Mon Feb 24 2014 08:00:26 GMT-0500 (EST)","timeDrift":-18000716,"event":"Started challenge","parameters":{"title":"Case 7: Challenge 1","route":"case7/challenge1","case":1,"challenge":1}},{"session":"e8a14c99-b18a-20a5-1d7e-cea199a1f605","time":1393246827235,"prettyTime":"Mon Feb 24 2014 08:00:27 GMT-0500 (EST)","timeDrift":-18000716,"event":"Opened info"},{"session":"e8a14c99-b18a-20a5-1d7e-cea199a1f605","time":1393246826599,"prettyTime":"Mon Feb 24 2014 08:00:26 GMT-0500 (EST)","timeDrift":-18000716,"event":"Moved to","parameters":{"title":"Case 7: Challenge 1"}},{"session":"e8a14c99-b18a-20a5-1d7e-cea199a1f605","time":1393246832961,"prettyTime":"Mon Feb 24 2014 08:00:32 GMT-0500 (EST)","timeDrift":-18000716,"event":"Closed info"},{"session":"e8a14c99-b18a-20a5-1d7e-cea199a1f605","time":1393246837613,"prettyTime":"Mon Feb 24 2014 08:00:37 GMT-0500 (EST)","timeDrift":-18000716,"event":"Opened info"},{"session":"e8a14c99-b18a-20a5-1d7e-cea199a1f605","time":1393246841872,"prettyTime":"Mon Feb 24 2014 08:00:41 GMT-0500 (EST)","timeDrift":-18000716,"event":"Closed info"},{"session":"e8a14c99-b18a-20a5-1d7e-cea199a1f605","time":1393246844062,"prettyTime":"Mon Feb 24 2014 08:00:44 GMT-0500 (EST)","timeDrift":-18000716,"event":"Opened info"},{"session":"e8a14c99-b18a-20a5-1d7e-cea199a1f605","time":1393246846333,"prettyTime":"Mon Feb 24 2014 08:00:46 GMT-0500 (EST)","timeDrift":-18000716,"event":"Closed info"},{"session":"e8a14c99-b18a-20a5-1d7e-cea199a1f605","time":1393246849025,"prettyTime":"Mon Feb 24 2014 08:00:49 GMT-0500 (EST)","timeDrift":-18000716,"event":"Bred dragons","parameters":{"mother":"a:T,b:T,a:m,b:m,a:W,b:W,a:h,b:h,a:C,b:C,a:B,b:B,a:fl,b:fl,a:hl,b:hl,a:A1,b:A1,a:D,b:D,a:Bog,b:Bog,a:rh,b:rh","father":"a:T,b:T,a:m,b:m,a:W,b:W,a:h,b:h,a:C,b:C,a:B,b:B,a:fl,b:fl,a:hl,b:hl,a:A1,b:A1,a:D,a:Bog,a:rh"}},{"session":"e8a14c99-b18a-20a5-1d7e-cea199a1f605","time":1393246850499,"prettyTime":"Mon Feb 24 2014 08:00:50 GMT-0500 (EST)","timeDrift":-18000716,"event":"Bred dragons","parameters":{"mother":"a:T,b:T,a:m,b:m,a:W,b:W,a:h,b:h,a:C,b:C,a:B,b:B,a:fl,b:fl,a:hl,b:hl,a:A1,b:A1,a:D,b:D,a:Bog,b:Bog,a:rh,b:rh","father":"a:T,b:T,a:m,b:m,a:W,b:W,a:h,b:h,a:C,b:C,a:B,b:B,a:fl,b:fl,a:hl,b:hl,a:A1,b:A1,a:D,a:Bog,a:rh"}},{"session":"e8a14c99-b18a-20a5-1d7e-cea199a1f605","time":1393246858866,"prettyTime":"Mon Feb 24 2014 08:00:58 GMT-0500 (EST)","timeDrift":-18000716,"event":"Changed allele","parameters":{"drakeId":1,"oldAlleles":"a:T,b:T,a:m,b:m,a:W,b:W,a:h,b:h,a:C,b:C,a:B,b:B,a:fl,b:fl,a:hl,b:hl,a:A1,b:A1,a:D,b:D,a:Bog,b:Bog,a:rh,b:rh","newAlleles":"a:T,b:T,a:m,b:M,a:W,b:W,a:h,b:h,a:C,b:C,a:B,b:B,a:fl,b:fl,a:hl,b:hl,a:A1,b:A1,a:D,b:D,a:Bog,b:Bog,a:rh,b:rh"}},{"session":"e8a14c99-b18a-20a5-1d7e-cea199a1f605","time":1393246861397,"prettyTime":"Mon Feb 24 2014 08:01:01 GMT-0500 (EST)","timeDrift":-18000716,"event":"Bred dragons","parameters":{"mother":"a:T,b:T,a:m,b:M,a:W,b:W,a:h,b:h,a:C,b:C,a:B,b:B,a:fl,b:fl,a:hl,b:hl,a:A1,b:A1,a:D,b:D,a:Bog,b:Bog,a:rh,b:rh","father":"a:T,b:T,a:m,b:m,a:W,b:W,a:h,b:h,a:C,b:C,a:B,b:B,a:fl,b:fl,a:hl,b:hl,a:A1,b:A1,a:D,a:Bog,a:rh"}},{"session":"e8a14c99-b18a-20a5-1d7e-cea199a1f605","time":1393246876642,"prettyTime":"Mon Feb 24 2014 08:01:16 GMT-0500 (EST)","timeDrift":-18000716,"event":"Changed allele","parameters":{"drakeId":2,"oldAlleles":"a:T,b:T,a:m,b:m,a:W,b:W,a:h,b:h,a:C,b:C,a:B,b:B,a:fl,b:fl,a:hl,b:hl,a:A1,b:A1,a:D,a:Bog,a:rh","newAlleles":"a:T,b:T,a:m,b:m,a:W,b:W,a:h,b:h,a:C,b:C,a:B,b:B,a:Fl,b:fl,a:hl,b:hl,a:A1,b:A1,a:D,a:Bog,a:rh"}},{"session":"e8a14c99-b18a-20a5-1d7e-cea199a1f605","time":1393246879950,"prettyTime":"Mon Feb 24 2014 08:01:19 GMT-0500 (EST)","timeDrift":-18000716,"event":"Bred dragons","parameters":{"mother":"a:T,b:T,a:m,b:M,a:W,b:W,a:h,b:h,a:C,b:C,a:B,b:B,a:fl,b:fl,a:hl,b:hl,a:A1,b:A1,a:D,b:D,a:Bog,b:Bog,a:rh,b:rh","father":"a:T,b:T,a:m,b:m,a:W,b:W,a:h,b:h,a:C,b:C,a:B,b:B,a:Fl,b:fl,a:hl,b:hl,a:A1,b:A1,a:D,a:Bog,a:rh"}},{"session":"e8a14c99-b18a-20a5-1d7e-cea199a1f605","time":1393246887521,"prettyTime":"Mon Feb 24 2014 08:01:27 GMT-0500 (EST)","timeDrift":-18000716,"event":"Opened info"},{"session":"e8a14c99-b18a-20a5-1d7e-cea199a1f605","time":1393246897648,"prettyTime":"Mon Feb 24 2014 08:01:37 GMT-0500 (EST)","timeDrift":-18000716,"event":"Closed info"},{"session":"e8a14c99-b18a-20a5-1d7e-cea199a1f605","time":1393246901125,"prettyTime":"Mon Feb 24 2014 08:01:41 GMT-0500 (EST)","timeDrift":-18000716,"event":"Changed allele","parameters":{"drakeId":1,"oldAlleles":"a:T,b:T,a:m,b:M,a:W,b:W,a:h,b:h,a:C,b:C,a:B,b:B,a:fl,b:fl,a:hl,b:hl,a:A1,b:A1,a:D,b:D,a:Bog,b:Bog,a:rh,b:rh","newAlleles":"a:T,b:T,a:m,b:M,a:W,b:w,a:h,b:h,a:C,b:C,a:B,b:B,a:fl,b:fl,a:hl,b:hl,a:A1,b:A1,a:D,b:D,a:Bog,b:Bog,a:rh,b:rh"}},{"session":"e8a14c99-b18a-20a5-1d7e-cea199a1f605","time":1393246903972,"prettyTime":"Mon Feb 24 2014 08:01:43 GMT-0500 (EST)","timeDrift":-18000716,"event":"Changed allele","parameters":{"drakeId":1,"oldAlleles":"a:T,b:T,a:m,b:M,a:W,b:w,a:h,b:h,a:C,b:C,a:B,b:B,a:fl,b:fl,a:hl,b:hl,a:A1,b:A1,a:D,b:D,a:Bog,b:Bog,a:rh,b:rh","newAlleles":"a:T,b:T,a:m,b:M,a:w,b:w,a:h,b:h,a:C,b:C,a:B,b:B,a:fl,b:fl,a:hl,b:hl,a:A1,b:A1,a:D,b:D,a:Bog,b:Bog,a:rh,b:rh"}},{"session":"e8a14c99-b18a-20a5-1d7e-cea199a1f605","time":1393246907580,"prettyTime":"Mon Feb 24 2014 08:01:47 GMT-0500 (EST)","timeDrift":-18000716,"event":"Changed allele","parameters":{"drakeId":2,"oldAlleles":"a:T,b:T,a:m,b:m,a:W,b:W,a:h,b:h,a:C,b:C,a:B,b:B,a:Fl,b:fl,a:hl,b:hl,a:A1,b:A1,a:D,a:Bog,a:rh","newAlleles":"a:T,b:T,a:m,b:m,a:w,b:W,a:h,b:h,a:C,b:C,a:B,b:B,a:Fl,b:fl,a:hl,b:hl,a:A1,b:A1,a:D,a:Bog,a:rh"}},{"session":"e8a14c99-b18a-20a5-1d7e-cea199a1f605","time":1393246918302,"prettyTime":"Mon Feb 24 2014 08:01:58 GMT-0500 (EST)","timeDrift":-18000716,"event":"Changed allele","parameters":{"drakeId":1,"oldAlleles":"a:T,b:T,a:m,b:M,a:w,b:w,a:h,b:h,a:C,b:C,a:B,b:B,a:fl,b:fl,a:hl,b:hl,a:A1,b:A1,a:D,b:D,a:Bog,b:Bog,a:rh,b:rh","newAlleles":"a:T,b:T,a:m,b:m,a:w,b:w,a:h,b:h,a:C,b:C,a:B,b:B,a:fl,b:fl,a:hl,b:hl,a:A1,b:A1,a:D,b:D,a:Bog,b:Bog,a:rh,b:rh"}},{"session":"e8a14c99-b18a-20a5-1d7e-cea199a1f605","time":1393246918188,"prettyTime":"Mon Feb 24 2014 08:01:58 GMT-0500 (EST)","timeDrift":-18000716,"event":"Moved to","parameters":{"title":"Case 7: Challenge 2"}},{"session":"e8a14c99-b18a-20a5-1d7e-cea199a1f605","time":1393246918189,"prettyTime":"Mon Feb 24 2014 08:01:58 GMT-0500 (EST)","timeDrift":-18000716,"event":"Started challenge","parameters":{"title":"Case 7: Challenge 2","route":"case7/challenge2","case":7,"challenge":2}},{"session":"e8a14c99-b18a-20a5-1d7e-cea199a1f605","time":1393246918195,"prettyTime":"Mon Feb 24 2014 08:01:58 GMT-0500 (EST)","timeDrift":-18000716,"event":"Closed info"},{"session":"e8a14c99-b18a-20a5-1d7e-cea199a1f605","time":1393246918492,"prettyTime":"Mon Feb 24 2014 08:01:58 GMT-0500 (EST)","timeDrift":-18000716,"event":"Changed allele","parameters":{"drakeId":2,"oldAlleles":"a:T,b:T,a:m,b:m,a:w,b:W,a:h,b:h,a:C,b:C,a:B,b:B,a:Fl,b:fl,a:hl,b:hl,a:A1,b:A1,a:D,a:Bog,a:rh","newAlleles":"a:T,b:T,a:m,b:m,a:w,b:w,a:h,b:h,a:C,b:C,a:B,b:B,a:fl,b:fl,a:hl,b:hl,a:A1,b:A1,a:D,a:Bog,a:rh"}},{"session":"e8a14c99-b18a-20a5-1d7e-cea199a1f605","time":1393246918713,"prettyTime":"Mon Feb 24 2014 08:01:58 GMT-0500 (EST)","timeDrift":-18000716,"event":"Closed info"},{"session":"e8a14c99-b18a-20a5-1d7e-cea199a1f605","time":1393246918746,"prettyTime":"Mon Feb 24 2014 08:01:58 GMT-0500 (EST)","timeDrift":-18000716,"event":"Opened info"},{"session":"e8a14c99-b18a-20a5-1d7e-cea199a1f605","time":1393246932466,"prettyTime":"Mon Feb 24 2014 08:02:12 GMT-0500 (EST)","timeDrift":-18000716,"event":"Closed info"}
```

Now, I want to parse it and store the records in database. How can it be parsed effectively and what would be a good way to store parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do using [`JSON::parse`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html#method-i-parse)

```
require 'json'

JSON.parse(string)
```

Example :

```
require 'json'

string = '{"session":"a24186c2-5536-1734-42cc-3eb50e625964","time":1392862093110}'
JSON.parse(string)
# => {"session"=>"a24186c2-5536-1734-42cc-3eb50e625964", "time"=>1392862093110}
```

**Update**

as per your comment do as below :

```
require 'json'

string = '[{"session":"a24186c2-5536-1734-42cc-3eb50e625964","time":1392862093110},{"sessi‌​on":"a24186c2-5536-1734-42cc-3eb50e625964","time":1392862093110}]'

array = JSON.parse(string)
# => [{"session"=>"a24186c2-5536-1734-42cc-3eb50e625964",
#      "time"=>1392862093110},
#     {"sessi‌​on"=>"a24186c2-5536-1734-42cc-3eb50e625964",
#      "time"=>1392862093110}]

array.each do |a|
  # your code
  puts a
end

# >> {"session"=>"a24186c2-5536-1734-42cc-3eb50e625964", "time"=>1392862093110}
# >> {"sessi‌​on"=>"a24186c2-5536-1734-42cc-3eb50e625964", "time"=>1392862093110}
```

Comment: But how should I split the data to separate individual json objects?

Comment: @Peeyush You have now Hash object from Json string. Now you can use Ruby's Hash API...

Comment: Let me try to clarify. Let's say data is `{"session":"a24186c2-5536-1734-42cc-3eb50e625964","time":1392862093110},{"session":"a24186c2-5536-1734-42cc-3eb50e625964","time":1392862093110}` How to separate the two parts in it?

Comment: Thanks for the help. This works! Now how should I access session value for a particular a. `a[session]` does not seem to work.